# The purpose of using CSRF token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, dropbox, csrf, dropbox-api

This is a question about Dropbox OAuth2.0 API and I think this could be about a common programming technique, so I decided to ask here.

The question is about this article.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api

What is the purpose of using CSRF which is written in the article which says that I should use CSRF token and "*verify the CSRF token matches the one you previously generated and stored*" ?
What kind of bad things could cause if I don't use CSRF token or I use CSRF token but I don't verify the CSRF token?
Maybe it could be possible that someone would delete files on my dropbox, but I don't know how.

Comment: It could be useful to read and understand a bit more about CSRF attacks before trying to understand why and how CSRF tokens help mitigate them. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I think the attackers at least must know authorization code to do bad things on my account. Am I right? I think they could not know the code.